# MSB4023 Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path ""

Tags: .net, build, msbuild

I started getting this error in the all .net6 apps build from last couple of days.

```
MSB4023 Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "Endpoint=https://xyz.azconfig.io". The given path's format is not supported.
```

When I build the project I started getting 3 more errors-
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error   MSB3030 Could not copy the file "Endpoint=https://xyz.azconfig.io" because it was not found.    ConsoleApp1 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    5215

Error   MSB3030 Could not copy the file "Id=uzRN-lo-s0:nfvf/KDPta7aI86ZLWe1" because it was not found.  ConsoleApp1 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    5215

Error   MSB3030 Could not copy the file "Secret=pjCrT0acZV8gobbW30MOtHeIK1S8Be8GNI0gKOnt0Ns=" because it was not found. ConsoleApp1 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    5215
```

I have tried below given ways with no luck-

- Clean the solution and rebuild
- Delete bin and obj folder and rebuild
- Close the visual studio and reopen and build
- Delete visual studio cache
- Uninstall visual with all features and install back.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What changed in the "last couple of days" around the time that the errors began? What troubleshooting and/or debugging steps have you already taken?

Comment: @JonathanDodds I added user secret for the application and after that I started getting this error. I cleaned up all user secrets from AppData and still the issue is there. Now I started getting this error for all .net builds. I also performed directorie search for the error files given but couldn't find anything. I have tried other possible workarounds given in the issue description.