# MSBuild issues in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

> Error MSB4023
> Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "Endpoint=https://configresource1325908.azconfig.io". The given path's format is not supported.
> WebApplication1 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

I am getting this error while trying to build a project even for the newly created web application in another solution.

I have tried modify Visual Studio, uninstalled and installed Visual Studio.

Comment: There are already [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76293264/msb4023cannot-evaluate-the-item-metadata-fullpath-the-item-metadata-fu) that [have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1288392/msb4023-cannot-evaluate-the-item-metadata) had the same problem. Apparently with no good answer. You might want to check them anyway. Possibly a binary msbuild log (run `msbuild.exe /bl`) could shed some light, but that is not a good fit for this side. You could try asking at the [MSBuild](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild) GitHub repo/issues.